# Configuring Spring's @DataJpaTest that overrides default application context beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I'm struggling with configuration for my @DataJpaTest. I'd like to take advantage of auto-configured spring context provided by @DataJpaTest, but I'd like to override some of it's beans.

This is my main class:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(BookInputPort bookInputPort) {
        return args -> {
            bookInputPort.addNewBook(new BookDto("ABC", "DEF"));
            bookInputPort.addNewBook(new BookDto("GHI", "JKL"));
            bookInputPort.addNewBook(new BookDto("MNO", "PRS"));
        };
    }
```

As you can clearly see, I provide my implementation for CommandLineRunner that depends on some service.

I also have a test:

```java
@DataJpaTest
public class BookRepositoryTest {

    public static final String TITLE = "For whom the bell tolls";
    public static final String AUTHOR = "Hemingway";

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Test
    public void testRepository() {
        Book save = bookRepository.save(new Book(TITLE, AUTHOR));
        assertEquals(TITLE, save.getTitle());
        assertEquals(AUTHOR, save.getAuthor());
    }
}
```

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.domain.book.ports.BookInputPort' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

That makes perfect sense! Auto-configured test provides implementation only for a 'slice' of the context. Apparently implementation of BookInputPort is missing. I do not need this commandLineRunner in a test context. I get create a commandLineRunner that does not depend on any service.
I can try to solve the issue by adding to my test class nested class :

```java
@TestConfiguration
    static class BookRepositoryTestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
            return args -> {
            };
        }
    }
```

That solves the problem. Kind of. If I had more tests like this I would have to copy-paste this nested class to each test class. It's not an optimal solution.
I tried to externalize this to a configuration that could be imported by `@Import`
This is the config class:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
        return args -> {
        };
    }
}
```

But then the application fails with a message:

```
Invalid bean definition with name 'commandLineRunner' defined in com.example.demo.DemoApplication: Cannot register bean definition
```

I checked that error and other folks on SO suggested in this case:

```java
@DataJpaTest(properties = "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true")
```

I did that and I got:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.domain.book.ports.BookInputPort' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

That is exactly the same problem I started with.
I took all these steps and found myself in the place where I was at the very beginning.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue? I do not have a vague idea or clue.

Comment: Why you want to add runner to test classes? the main runner  is ok. It will run in the test context

Comment: @muasif80 Yes, the runner runs in the test context. That is exactly the issue. Runner implementation in main class requires service that is not created in test context (autoconfigured test like DataJpaTest or WebMvcTest create only a slice of original context without classes annotated with Service or Component - as stated in spring docs. In such case test application context fails to start due to missing BookInputPort in CommandLineRunner impl in main class. This leads to failing context and in consequence failing test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Boot test class you can do it like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class YourClassTest {

    @Autowired
    private YourService yourService;
```

It does load all the services and I am using it perfectly fine

**How to load specific entities in one environment and not the other**

1. You can use `@Profile` annotation in your entities.
2. Put `@Profile({"prod"})` on entities/services you don't want to load in test run, and
3. Put `@Profile({"prod", "test"})` on entities/services you want to load in both `test` and `prod` environments
4. Then run the `test` with `test` profile. It will not load unnecessary `entities`.
5. You can put `@Profile` annotation on other services too.

Comment: thank you for the provided solution. My goal however was to run this limited context that would be enough for JpaRepository testing. I'm aware that your solution is proper and solves this problem in general. I just would like to prevent from loading more beans than required. At this point I do not know whether my approach is even doable.

Answer (score 3):

@DataJpaTest generally starts scanning from current package of the test class and scans upwards till it finds the class annotated with @SpringBootConfiguration. 
 
 So creating a SpringBootConfiguration class at the repository root package will create only beans defined within that package. On top of that we can add any customized test bean required for our test class in that configuration class.

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestRepositoryConfig {

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
        return args -> {
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public BookInputPort bootInputPort(){
        return new BookInputPort();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The annotation  `@DataJpaTest` only loads the JPA part of a Spring Boot application, the application context might not loaded because you have  `@DataJpaTest` annotation. Try to replace the `@DataJpaTest` with  `@SpringBootTest`.

As per [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html):

> By default, tests annotated with `@DataJpaTest` will use an embedded
>   in-memory database (replacing any explicit or usually auto-configured
>   DataSource). The `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` annotation can be used to
>   override these settings. If you are looking to load your full
>   application configuration, but use an embedded database, you should
>   consider `@SpringBootTest` combined with `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase`
>   rather than this annotation.

Comment: "the application context might not loaded because you have @DataJpaTest annotation" This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I think actually that is your problem.

Comment: You could be right and it could be done by SpringBootTest. It's just a matter of externalizing some configuration (in this case configuration with only implementation of CommandLineRunner) and using it in test class. I'm trying to grasp why configuration provided in nested static class and annotated with TestConfiguration works, while externalizing it to separate class doesn't. BR

Comment: It is also worth to mention that loading the entire context with @SpringBootTest takes more time, so You should only do it if necessary as ultimately it will slow down Your test suite substantially

Comment: I think he does want to not have the default context (his main application context) loaded, but have a separate context. propably because of some special datasource beans.
Meaning to overwrite the default context which is used when using SpringBootTest